# method that accepts two double arrays as parameters, returning true only if all values in the array are equal(within .001 threshold)

Tags: java

I'm not the best but this is what I have so far. Whenever I change any of the elements in `array1`, it still holds true even if it is above a `.001` threshold. Where did I go wrong?

```
public static boolean equals(double[] arr1, double[] arr2) {
    if (arr1.length != arr2.length)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
        if ((arr1[i] - arr2[i]) < .001) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    question2 object = new question2();
    double[] arr1 = { 95.0, 14.0, 16.5, 11.1 };
    double[] arr2 = { 95.0, 12.9, 16.5, 11.1 };
    System.out.println(question3.equals(arr1, arr2));
```

Comment: what is question3?

Comment: Side note: `if ((arr1[i] - arr2[i]) < .001)`: I think you need to compare the absolute value of the difference to your threshold

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, this script will return true if ANY of the array elements are within 0.001.
You need to reverse your logic/thinking.
You want to return false if any of the array elements are NOT within 0.001.

Also consider if array 2 is greater than array 1. Their difference will be negative in that case. You probably want to take the absolute value of the difference and see if THAT is less than 0.001.

Comment: thank you very much! this helped a lot and I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning true if `any` value difference is less than `0.001` which is wrong as you should compare all of them

secondly, You need to compare `Absolute` value to check threshold as in some cases value of `2nd array` can be greater than 1st so it will voilate the condition, so try this:

```
public static boolean equals(double[] arr1, double[] arr2) {
    if (arr1.length != arr2.length)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
        if (Math.abs(arr1[i] - arr2[i]) >= .001) {  // <-- Note Absolute difference
            return false;   //here if any value voilates the rule it should return false
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Using a break at the point of voilation will be efficient for a looping execution.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if ((arr1[i] - arr2[i]) < .001)
```

With

```
 if (Math.abs(arr1[i] - arr2[i]) < .001)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem in  your logic.You should write code like this

boolean test = true;

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {

        if (Math.abs((arr1[i] - arr2[i])) > .001) {

            test = false;
            break;

        }
    }

    return test;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason being, the code is checking for the first occurrence of true scenario from the array and it is returning as True.

```
    public static boolean equals(double[] arr1, double[] arr2) {
    if (arr1.length != arr2.length)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
        if ((arr1[i] - arr2[i]) < .001) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Code flow will come to false return statement, only if, the 'if' condition doesn't match for all the comparison.
    return false;
}

double[] arr1 = { 95.0, 14.0, 16.5, 11.1 };
double[] arr2 = { 95.0, 12.9, 16.5, 11.1 };
// Will return True on first occurrence (95.0-95.0 < .001) and the code flow goes back to the function call and print as True.
```

Check the below solution:

```
    public static boolean equals(double[] arr1, double[] arr2) {
    if (arr1.length != arr2.length)
        return false;
    boolean flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
        if (arr1[i] - arr2[i] < .001) {
            flag = true;
        } else {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}
```